# Program never ends on TimeoutException in java

Tags: java, concurrency, future

I am trying a java program to understand working of `Future`.

I wrote following program and it never ends. If I put a value that is less than 10 in `Thread.sleep()`, then it works but not for values `>=10`.

[image]

I understood the part that is causing problem is probably the future.get call.

However, on further analysis, what I tried was, to handle all the exceptions and not letting jvm handle them.

eg:
[image]

Now it terminated fine.

I did a further check and saw that if I throw `ExecutionException` and `InterruptedException` and handle `TimeoutException` it works fine again.
Here strange part is I have to compulsorily handle TimeoutException, else it will not work. I am not so sure why this strange behaviour persists.

I am using OpenJDK 15.

If anybody wants to try code snippet its here:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class FixedThreadPoolExecutorDemo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        workWithFutureCallable(executorService);
        executorService.shutdownNow();
    }

    private static void workWithFutureCallable(ExecutorService executorService) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {

        Future<Integer> myOtherFuture = executorService.submit(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(109);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            return 1000;
        });
        System.out.println("myOtherFuture  should be cancelled if running for more than specified time. ->" + myOtherFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

    }
}
```

Comment: as the Exception is passed on, the executor service is not shut down and it is using a non-daemon Thread. Doc of `newFixedThreadPool`:  *"The threads in the pool will exist until it is explicitly shutdown"*. Use (create) a `ThreadFactory` that create daemon `Thread`s or (better IMO) use `try-finally` to always shut down

Comment: ` executorService.shutdownNow();` is called in the code if you see.

Comment: You must be able to catch the thread interruption in the main method and that should exit the application.

Comment: additionally, I saw that it goes in uncaughtException method of threadgroup, there it prints stacktrace and moves ahed if it does not see instanceof `ThreadDeath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TimeoutException` is not being caught in `main`, so `main` is also terminating abruptly **without** calling `shutdownNow`. The main thread is terminated but the threads created by `Executors` are non-daemon by default, so the virtual machine is not shut down, the `Executors` thread(s) continue running.

Solution:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        try {
            workWithFutureCallable(executorService);
        } finally {
            executorService.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
```

or

implement a `ThreadFactory` to create daemon threads and use it to get the service:

```
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2, r -> {
            var thread = new Thread(r);
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            return thread;
        });
```

Even better, at least in production code, catch and handle the `Exception`s (together with the `finally` block.)

Comment: Hi @user15244370 , I am sorry, I could not understand same thing via your comments.
I added finally block and it worked. Indeed, I did not think that threads created by executorservice are non-daemon threads. Thank you very much.
Also, here I am studying about concurrency, so yes, production grade code will handle and will also note that shutdown of executorservice should be in finally block only.